Заблокировать переход по ссылке
В событии
onclik

Использовал
e.preventDefault()

Чтобы заблокировать переход по ссылке, аналогично как заблокировать если срабатывает событие
onpointerdown

Googl hrome, если вешать слушатель onpointerdown на ссылку и пытаться заблокировать. Не работает, переходит по ссылке, как решить это?

И..............

А в чём вопрос?

Срабатывает переадресация, не блокируется клик по ссылке. Поправил вопрос...

Вы не можете заблокировать переход по ссылке. Уберите ссылку если хотите чтобы по ней не прошли.

Ну или через css добавить pointer-events: none;, но не советую. Этот атрибут блокирует все пользовательские действия.

Ровно так же, как и с onClick:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://example.com" id="myLink">Ссылка на что-то</a>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('myLink').onpointerdown = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Дополнительные действия можно делать здесь
            console.log('Переход по ссылке заблокирован');
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Переадресовывает. pointerdown - срабатывает когда нажимаем, а когда отпускаем срабатывает переход. Получается, что блокируем переход до того прежде чем браузер переадресует. Хз, но меня переадресовывает, когда отпускаю зажатую клавишу на мыше...

Меня одно перенаправляет при клике, в чем дело?

Googl hrome....

Мне одного интересно как общаются автор вопроса и автор этого ответа? Вопроса как бы не было, на что вы ответили?
